# Simple ASP.NET MVC app with only administrator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am dealing with a pretty simple app that just displays not so valuable data from the DB. So I dont care too much about safety. The only thing I need is to implement AuthControl, which asks for only password, compares it with predefined (static string right in code) one and sets IsAuthorized property to true.

**Improtant: I dont need to save user o the DB. I dont have any users. Only one guy who knows his password and who is able to access CRUD operations**.

Should I customize `[Authorize]` attribute to achieve that or there is more simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [forms authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx) built into MVC. It allows to store the passwords in the web.config, so no DB is needed.

web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/" protection="None">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="admin" password="adminpassword" />
         </credentials>
     </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
 </system.web>
```

The `AccountController` should be scaffolded if you create a new MVC project (New project -> ASP.NET Web Application -> MVC).
Login action in this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return View(model);
    }

    // we use simple forms authentication with a list of user in the web.config file 
    if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password)) {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserName, false);
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong username or password");
    return View(model);
}
```